# Why did Global Texture Coordinate disappeared in Blender 2.80?

Tags: texturing

Global Texture Coordinate disappeared in Blender 2.80

I need *Global* texture coordinate for boolean cut texture animation

[image]

Comment: global? would you mind putting in a screenshot of what you mean?

Comment: Ok, i post image screenshot

Comment: Hello. You must edit the question. Put the image there.

Comment: I edit post and upload image screenshot

Comment: what version of blender was that? And where do you exactly find the panel, in what mode. The information would be useful and save time.

Comment: Blender 2.79 Only "Blender Render" working fine, In Blender 2.80 "Eevee" "Cycles" not exist Global

Answer (score 4):

You could always use the Object Space of an Empty placed at 0 of, and aligned to, the World Axes:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The global coordinates where [an option that only existed for the Blender Internal render engine](https://docs.blender.org/manual/es/2.79/render/blender_render/textures/properties/mapping.html#coordinates).

> **Global**
>
> The scene’s global 3D coordinates. This is also useful for
>   animations; if you move the object, the texture moves across it. It
>   can be useful for letting objects appear or disappear at a certain
>   position in space.

It wasn't and [isn't an option in Cycles or Eevee](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/texture_coordinate.html#outputs). The closest equivalent would be the *Camera* output of the *Texture Coordinate* node.

> **Camera**
>
> Position coordinate in camera space.

Answer (score 1):

You know.. I thought there used to be a Texture Coordinate option called "World" or "Global", but I can't find any evidence that there ever was. At any rate, it's not an option now. But I found using the Geometry:Position output hooked up to the Mapping:Vector input has the same effect of a texture changing as the mesh moves through space.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).